# Callback on host node after slurm job has been allocated

Tags: slurm

I'd like to do two things in sequence:

1. Submit a job with `sbatch`
2. Once the job has been allocated, retrieve the `hostname` of the allocated node and, using that name, execute a second command on the *host* (login) node.

Step 2 is the hard part. I suppose I could write a Python script that polls `squeue`. Is there a better way? Can I set up a callback that Slurm will execute once a job starts running?

(In case you're curious, my motivation is to launch a Jupyter notebook on a compute node and automatically set up ssh port forwarding as in [this blog post](https://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/running-jupyter-notebooks-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh/).)

Comment: Can you just use the sbatch output environment variable SLURM_SUBMIT_HOST in your batch script to retrieve the hostname of the login node, then run something in your batch script to run on the login node?

Comment: By the way, polling ```squeue``` is a very, very bad idea if you do it too fast. It can really slow down the scheduler and make the admins and other users very upset at you.